# Alfresco & Solr SSL Cert handshake timeout

Tags: ssl, solr, alfresco

Server configuration:

Alfresco Community 4.0.e on Windows 2003 server

MySQL 5.5.27.3

MySQL Connector 5.1.22

I used the Windows installer to install Alfresco. The only deviation from the stock answers to the Advanced installation was to change the database driver settings:

db.driver=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
db.name=alfresco
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/alfresco?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Solr settings in config, as set by the installer:
dir.root=C:/Alfresco/alf_data
index.subsystem.name=solr
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
solr.port.ssl=8443

Error message from catalina.log file:

```
WARNING: Exception getting SSL attributes
java.net.SocketException: SSL Cert handshake timeout
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport.handShake(JSSESupport.java:189)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport.getPeerCertificateChain(JSSESupport.java:143)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:1116)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SSLAuthenticator.authenticate(SSLAuthenticator.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

How do I fix this? Suggestions? I haven't changed any of the stock configuration other than the MySQL install. The Alfresco tables were created without problems when Tomcat was started and I browsed to the Admin page at localhost:8080/Alfresco.

BTW, both Solr and Alfresco are hosted in the same Tomcat6 instance.
I tried to regen the keys as suggested by [this post](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=46080), but it didn't help.
Still get the same error. This must have something to do with the Server2003 configuration.

Comment: That's strange, I also did a clean installation and it was fine. The timeout you're getting isn't related to the old keys. Hence it looks like 8443 isn't passing through. Have you tried changing the ports to the default windows 443 ports?

Comment: Actually, it was a really stupid problem. Or stupid solution. Alfresco & Solr didn't like the version of Java that I had already installed on the machine. I reinstalled Alfresco and selected the Java that came with the installer, and all problems went away. Makes no sense to me, unless there's a bug in the jre7 I had installed. Anyways, it's fixed now. Dumb.

Comment: jre7 is not supported yet (but coming up!).

Comment: I don't really think there is an issue with that. If there was Alfresco &/or SOLR shouldn't start at all. Hence I think your certificates weren't injected within the Java security correctly. But glad to know it is fixed

Comment: The only difference between Alfresco/Solr working and not working was using the version of Java included with the Windows exe installer. I tried a bunch of configurations and installations. I needed to use the version of java included with the installation. Silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to use the version of java included with the 4.0.e windows installer. Using any other version that I had installed on the machine prevented it from working ( 6 and 7 ).